# EM algorithm update step formula

Tags: hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, baum-welch

I'm using these formulas to update my initial vector, transition matrix and emission matrix:
[image]

I have update my initial vector fine using formula (1) but the other two formula have an alpha instead of equal sign so I'm not really sure how to use them. I have no trouble evaluating the right hand side I just don't know what to do with it.

edit: after thinking about it for a while longer, I think the answer is to divide the RHS by N, any comment agreeing or disagreeing with this would still be appreciated

**What changes can I make to the RHS of formula (2) and (3) so the "$\propto$" can be replaced by an "$=$" and I can use the formula in my program?**

Comment: Could you comment and tell me how to improve my question rather than just downvoting it?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I use formula (2) and (3) to find the value of the LHS when they have an $\alpha$ instead of =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the left-hand sides of these formulas are probabilities, you should normalize their right-hand sides such that they become valid probability distributions, i.e., sum to one.

Specifically, you should divide the RHS of formula (2) by
$$\sum_{j}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{t=1}^{T_n-1}p^{old}(h_t=i,h_{t+1}=j|v^n)$$

Likewise, you should divide the RHS of formula (3) by
$$\sum_{k}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{t=1}^{T_n}\text I[v^n_t=k] p^{old}(h_t=i|v^n)$$